# Why using AES in ECB (Electronic Code Book) mode a bad idea?

Tags: aes, modes-of-operation, ecb

Why using AES in ECB (Electronic Code Book) mode a bad idea? is CTR mode better? Given only these two can be used for parallelization.

Comment: On the other hand, that makes your post's title completely different from your post's body. $\;$

Comment: There are other parallelizable modes as well. Such as XTS and OCB. But to recommend a mode we need to understand your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

ECB is bad because identical plaintext blocks result in identical ciphertext blocks. Encrypted data is therefore not pseudo-random.

This is how Tux looks like after ECB encryption:

[image: ECB Tux]

CTR mode doesn't have this problem. Data encrypted with CTR mode is pseudo-random and doesn't show any pattern. So CTR is much better.

CBC and CFB can also decrypt parallel, but not encrypt.